# My netty client program is not receiving any response from server

Tags: java, server, socket.io, client, netty

I have written a client-server programme using netty IO in which I am able to send a message to the server and server responds back but unfortunately, any of the listener methods in my Client Handler class is not getting invoked ie.. response is not received at the client level back. This is the piece of code used in my client to send a request message to the server.

```
ChannelFuture cf =this.ctx.channel().writeAndFlush(Unpooled.copiedBuffer(getEchoISOMessage(), CharsetUtil.ISO_8859_1));
this.ctx.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.EMPTY_BUFFER);
cf.awaitUninterruptibly();
if (!cf.isSuccess()) {
    System.out.println("Send failed: " + cf.cause());
}
```

Below is the code used to receive any response message from the server.

```
 @Override
public  void ChannelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf in)
{
    System.out.println("Received a response from Server..");
    String responseMessage="";
    responseMessage=in.toString(CharsetUtil.ISO_8859_1);
    System.out.println("Received data as echo response"+responseMessage+"from "+ctx.channel().remoteAddress());

}
```

But this method is not getting invoked at all.

Comment: What does your pipeline look like?

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I have only one handler and nothing more. But any of the callback methods in the handlers are not invoked.

Answer (score 1):

What does your handler extend from? It should be an inbound handler if it is to receive a response from the server. Are you sure your code compiles with the `@Override` annotation? The callback method in `ChannelInboundHanlder` is `public void void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg)`. Make sure your annotate with `@Override` and make sure the code compiles. Then your client will/should receive the response from the server. If it doesn't help, consider sharing the full code.